# Typescript does not recognize the correct generic type with index access

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to process nested arrays of two different objects with the same type.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NDP04N)

The type `ArrayProperties` returns the correct type definition.

```
type ArrayProperties<T> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Array<any> ? P : never]: T[P];
}
```

I do not understand why Typescript won't recognize the correct types in the function body of `concatArrays`.

```
function concatArrays<Type extends object, Prop extends keyof ArrayProperties<Type>>
  (arr1: Type, arr2: Type, prop: Prop) {
    const a = arr1[prop];
    const b = arr2[prop];
    // Why are a and b of type any and not of type Array?
    return a.concat(b);  // `Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'Type[Prop]'.`
}
```

Example:

```
const arr1 = {
    bla: 'str',
    foo: [1, 2]
};

const arr2 = {
    bla: 'ing',
    foo: [3, 4]
};

const result = concatArrays(arr1, arr2, 'foo');
// result type should be number[]

const typeError = concatArrays(arr1, arr2, 'bla'); // type error => correct
```

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728).  The compiler is not smart enough to do higher order generic type analysis.  If you want the compiler to know that `Type[Prop]` is an array, you need to constrain `Type` as well as (or instead of) `Prop`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZrKom).  See the answer to the other question for details.

Comment: Once that issue is solved, you still have `any[]` coming out because `T[K]` is widened to the constraint `any[]` upon dereferencing with `concat`.  Again, this is because the desired type manipulation (e.g., `T[K]["concat"]` operates on an array of element type `T[K][number]`) is too difficult for the compiler to do.  A type assertion is probably the best way to proceed there, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdjbnW)

Comment: Since the latter issue depends on the former one being solved, and the former one is a duplicate of several other questions, you might want to either make a new post for just the latter issue, or [edit] this question to fix the part which is answered by the other questions and/or show how this question differs significantly from them.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer although my question is a duplicate. I can solve the latter issue by type assertion, as you said. However to keep it generic I will use `return a.concat(b) as any as T[K];`